# Is there any research on the (possible) ancient origins of populations in different regions in Cyprus and their movements on the island?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-greece, cyprus

I was looking at a map of the kingdoms of ancient Cyprus where each kingdom was presented to have had either Greek majority , Phoenician majority or was mixed Greek/Eteocypriot so I was wondering if I can find any source that provides more details on this.
In this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_city-kingdoms_of_Cyprus) you can see a wikipedia article listing the kingdoms in Cyprus and their respective reigning ethnicities/majorities(?).

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing some of those maps. It would help with writing answers too. It would also help better delineate the period you are interested in.

Comment: Here is one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_city-kingdoms_of_Cyprus. This one doesn't list the majorities of each kingdom very explicitly though. I am interested inany  period from 2000BC to 1900 A.D .

Comment: @GEP Please update your question with any new information when asked for clarification.

Comment: Something more sciency about modern day demography: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0179474. Similar work about genetic origin from neolithic to iron age has been done on Sicilly (or Sardinia ?). But i can't find the publication now ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot depends on the time-scale you are asking about. Evidence is spotty the further back you go. Many different populations settled or conquered Cyprus over the centuries.

According to the Wikipedia article "[Ancient history of Cyprus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_history_of_Cyprus)", Mycenaean settlers arrived in the twelfth century BCE and Assyrian conquest took place by about 700 BCE. The [ten city-kingdoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_city-kingdoms_of_Cyprus) documented c. 673 were primarily Greek, with the exceptions of Kition (Greco-Phoenician) and Amathus (Greco-Eteocypriot). This was followed by a brief Egyptian conquest, then Persian rule up until the Hellenistic conquest by Alexander the Great. Cyprus became a Roman province in 58 BCE.

So clearly the story will be very complicated if you want to cover all of Cyrpus over all that time. If you would like more detail about the late prehistoric period 6th-4th centuries BCE in particular, [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00438243.1977.9979683) is an article that looks worth tracking down.